# How can I get notified every time a user purchases my iOS app from the App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

As the title says, how can I get notified every time a user purchases my iOS app from the App Store?

Is it even possible?

It’d be cool to have some script play a cash register sound every time I made a sale.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this using iTunes Connect, but, you could notify a remote server when your app is opened for the first time. This won't be 100% accurate as someone can buy your app, delete it and install it again.

Comment: I figured it would be impossible with iTunes Connect, but is there any way to improve the accuracy of the other approach you mention using some clever tricks? If only we still had `UIDevice`’s `uniqueIdentifier` property…

Comment: For your usecase using UIDevice's identifierForVendor should be accurate enough